# Compare 2 expressions with variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test, function-comparison

I want to check if two expressions are equivalent with Mathematica. For example, is $2 x + 4 + 2$ equivalent to $2 (x + 2 + 1)$.
I tried the `===` operator, which I expected to return `True` in both examples.

```
In[]:= 2 x + 4 + 2 === 2 (x + 2 + 1)
Out[]:= False
```

```
In[]:= 2 x + 4 + 2 === x + 6 + x
Out[]:= True
```

I also tried `==` operator, which just returned the whole expression for one example and `True` for the other.

```
In[]:= 2 x + 4 + 2 == 2 (x + 2 + 1)
Out[]:= 6 + 2 x == 2 (3 + x)
```

```
In[]:= 2 x + 4 + 2 == x + 6 + x
Out[]:= True
```

So my question is there another operator/function that determines whether or not two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Try `Simplify[2 x + 4 + 2 == 2 (x + 2 + 1)]`. Do not use `===`; that's for structural identity. Your two expressions are identical *in meaning*, but not *in structure*, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Sadly `Simplify` doesn't always fit my needs. For example: `Simplify[8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]]]` and `Simplify[x^(15/8)/(15/8)]` do not return the same result although the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ` can be useful for this.

Comment: @NejcJezersek No they are not for some complex values. You can find a counterexample: `FindInstance[8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]]  !=  x^(15/8)/(15/8), x]` which returns `{{x -> -(28/5) + (79 I)/5}}` as an example of a value for which the two expressions are different. Alternatively, you can `Simplify` the difference of the two and see if it reduces to $0$.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you; `FindInstance[
 8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]] != x^(15/7)/(15/8), x, Reals]` with domain specified does the job for me.

Comment: @NejcJezersek Glad it helped! If you want a more general result, `Reduce[8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]] == x^(15/7)/(15/8), x, Reals]` indicates that the identity is really only true for $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: `x` being real is not sufficient: `8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]] == x^(15/8)/(15/8) /. x -> -1` evaluates to `False`. You need to assume that `x` is nonnegative: `Simplify[8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]] == x^(15/8)/(15/8), x >= 0]` evaluates to `True`. Look at `FunctionDomain[8/15 x Sqrt[x Sqrt[x^(3/2)]] - x^(15/8)/(15/8), x]`

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[x, 2 x + 4 + 2 == 2 (x + 2 + 1)]]` gives `True`

Comment: Sometimes, especially with a complex algebraic expression, you need to 'give Mathematica a hand'  by manipulating one or both sides of the expression (and `==` can then be very powerful).  `Simplify[2 x + 4 + 2] == 2 (x + 2 + 1)` or `2 x + 4 + 2 == Apart[2 (x + 2 + 1)]` or `2 x + 4 + 2 == Expand[2 (x + 2 + 1)]` or `Factor[2 x + 4 + 2] == 2 (x + 2 + 1)` all give 'True' (and there are many other useful commands such as `TrigExpand`, `PowerExpand` etc)

Answer (score 2):

A predicate command returns either True or False. Always. The Equal command (==) is not a predicate in that sense. In many cases, Equal returns neither, instead Equal just returns the entire expression without change. Mathematica does not know if they are equal.

The SameQ command is a predicate. It returns True if both arguments are structurally identical (using some simple algrebra too), otherwise False. Always. But there are some expressions that are mathematically equal, but not structurally equal. And it can be proven that it is not always possible to determine this in all cases.

PossibleZeroQ is also a predicate dealing essentially with (lhs-rhs). I'm not sure, but I think it works by substituting random numbers (perhaps complex numbers) for all the symbols. Multiple times. If ~0 is obtained during all these experiments, it returns True. PossibleZeroQ is a very well-named command.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky it is, for example, see the following somewhat inconsistent results.
[image]